# Linq Query to Group by and Sum into new list

Tags: c#, linq

So I'm having a little nightmare trying to construct a query, even though it really shouldn't be so difficult.

I have a class visitItem

```
public class visitItem
{
    public int visitId {get; set;}
    public int contactId {get; set;}
    public int locationId {get; set;}
    public DateTime FirstSeen {get; set;}
    public DateTime LastSeen {get; set;}
    public double Duration {get; set;}
}
```

Basically I have visit history date in a json which I deserialize to a list of `visitItem` and form several different charts from the data.

What I'm wanting to do is create a new list from the main list where I select a particular month, and the resulting list is now grouped by contactId and the duration is summed:

```
List<visitItem> totalDurations = visits
  .Where(x => x.FirstSeen.ToString("MM") == month)......
```

So that selects the relevant month of data and then I want the list to be like:

```
contactId          duration
1                  10
2                  5
3                  5
4                  20
```

instead of:

```
contactId          duration
1                  5
1                  5 
2                  5
3                  5
4                  10
4                  10
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why are you performing string conversions at all? Surely using `FirstSeen.Month` would be simpler... Anyway, you haven't explained *why* you want the first output, or what the inputs are... currently you've just said you want it to be X instead of Y, which gives us very little context with which to help yuo...

Comment: Ah - after reformatting the question, it makes more sense. Please take care to preview the question before you post it, to make sure it actually makes sense.

Comment: Next, you *say* you've grouped by contactId, but you haven't shown that part of the query at all, which again makes it hard to help. Ideally, provide a short but complete program demonstrating the problem...

Comment: Sorry for the bad formatting in the original post. I just looked back at it now and I thought I'd constructed my answer exactly as above post-edit. I didn't meant to say I'd grouped by contactId, my implication was that I get a relevant list by first selecting only visits from month x. And this resulting list should then be grouped and summed etc. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to filter by month, then group items by contact id, and then sum the durations for those groups.  For example, for May:

```
var month = 5;

var durationByContact = from visit in visits
                        where visit.FirstSeen.Month == month
                        group visit by visit.contactId
                        into visitsByContact
                        select new
                        {
                            ContactId = visitsByContact.Key,
                            TotalDuration = visitsByContact.Sum(i => i.Duration)
                        };
```

Or in method syntax:

```
var durationByContact = visits
    .Where(v => v.FirstSeen.Month == month)
    .GroupBy(v => v.contactId)
    .Select(g => new
    {
        ContactId = g.Key,
        TotalDuration = g.Sum(i => i.Duration)
    });
```

Comment: No, it's *filtering* by month and *grouping* by contact ID.

Comment: @JonSkeet you're correct - the question edit explains better I'm not sure it was clear before.  I've updated.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is exactly what I wanted. I just edited it to `Select(g => new visitItem{ContactId = g.Key, Duration = g.Sum(i => i.Duration})` to make it easy to use in a foreach loop and avoid a list of an anonymous type.

Comment: As an additional query, how would I include FirstSeen in the select portion of the query? e.g. `.Select(g => new visitItem{ContactId = g.Key, TotalDuration = g.Sum(i => i.Duration), FirstSeen = ???});`

Comment: What value of `FirstSeen` do you want? As you're only grouping by `contactId`, `FirstSeen` could have various values in that group (though all in `month` as you've filtered by that first).